# Adding textboxes to a panel without space between them

Tags: c#, textbox, coordinates, panel

### I have a panel and a button that adds text boxes to the panel in the following configuration:

### |   textbox1 |

### | textbox2   |

etc.
The vertical width of each textbox is 27 so what I do is keep track of a y-coordinate and add 30 to it every time I make a new textbox, and put the textbox at that y coordinate. The problem is that after a few textboxes a scrollbar appears, and when I add a new textbox, the origin is taken to be at the top left corner of the visible portion of the panel, not the top left corner of the complete panel. This results in a lot of space between some textboxes. Can anyone help me fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Show some code on how you are adding these TextBoxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) instead.  Then you could just add your textboxes by doing `flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(mytextbox1);`

The other option is explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808947/how-do-i-fix-the-autoscroll-from-moving-my-point-of-origin-in-a-forms-based-progr) post.

Another example is [Setting position of a control doesn't seem to work when scroll is 'moved'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314611/setting-position-of-a-control-doesnt-seem-to-work-when-scroll-is-moved-c-wi)

Comment: Looks like you beat me too it :P

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Even if it seems strange to me that origin "shifts", try aftrr that you added last TextBox add your Delta from its Bounds.Bottom which will generate Top of next TextBox to add.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a Flowlayout Panel?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx